# Make [mata] a synonym for [stata]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I am one of the main and active contributors to the [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata) tag. A couple
days ago I suggested that [mata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mata) be made a synonym of [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata).

Stata has two distinct programming languages, with `mata` being its more specialized matrix language. This typically acts as complementary to the main `ado` language and I thus strongly believe that it would be beneficial for our community to automatically re-map any `mata`-related future questions to `stata`.

At the moment, it appears that the only viable solution for approving tag synonyms in smaller communities where there are not enough active users with sufficient reputation to vote is for moderators to approve it instead.

I would thus kindly request for a moderator to approve this synonym.

Comment: Synonym request approved.